# basic mathematical function

Tags: functions

I have a basic question.
When I store 10000 objects in a locker for 10000000 years, I lose 1 object. How many objects should I have, if I want to lose the same 1 object in 1 year. Is it `10000000 * 1000?`

Comment: You're close: do you have an explanation of how you concluded this, and did you type what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

Try multiplying each term in your product by $10$, unless you have a typo that you overlooked.

That is you need to have the same number of objects $\times$ the same number of years (in which you'd lose one object), in order to lose 1 object in only one year.

In other words, if "I store $\bf x$ objects in a locker for $\bf y$ years, I lose 1 object...", so if I want to lose the same 1 object in 1 year I need to have $\bf x\times y$ objects.

Are you clear as to why?